# Need to build a url and work with the returned result

Tags: ruby, http-post

I would like to start with a little script that fetches the examination results of me and my friends from our [university website](http://www.nitt.edu/prm/ShowResult.htm).

I would like to pass it the roll number as the post parameter and work with the returned data,
I don't know how to create the post string.

It would be great if someone could tell me where to start, what are the things to learn, links to a tutorial would be most appreciated.

I don´t want someone to write code for me, just guidance on how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a solution here just as a reference for whatever you might come up with. There are multiple ways of attacking this.

```
#fetch_scores.rb

require 'open-uri'

#define a constant named URL so if the results URL changes we don't
#need to replace a hardcoded URL everywhere.
URL = "http://www.nitt.edu/prm/ShowResult.html?&param="

#checking the count of arguments passed to the script.
#it is only taking one, so let's show the user how to use
#the script
if ARGV.length != 1
  puts "Usage: fetch_scores.rb student_name"
else
  name = ARGV[0] #could drop the ARGV length check and add a default using ||
  # or   name = ARGV[0] || nikhil
  results = open(URL + name).read
end
```

You might examine [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) to better parse/format your results. Ruby is an "implicit return" language so if you happened to wonder why we didn't have a return statement that's because results will be returned by the script since it was last executed.

Comment: This looks like what i want, but the form there takes POST data, passing in arguments this way lead to a 404 page not found error.
How can I make a HTTP POST request this way?

Comment: You will want to look at [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) and change out the use of `open-uri` with `net/http`. Open-uri unfortunately just lets you use `GET`. The method you will probably need from `net/http` is: `Net::HTTP.post_form`. The examples look to be utilizing `URI` as well. There should be enough sample code on that page for you to get it working.

Comment: Thanks i´ve made some progress, hopefully iĺl be able to get this done soon.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the net/http library, included as part of the standard library. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html for details, there are some examples on that page to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is to use the `open-uri` library and just put the query parameters in the URL query string:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
name = 'nikhil'
results = open("http://www.nitt.edu/prm/ShowResult.html?&param=#{name}").read
```

`results` now contains the body text fetched from the URL.

If you are looking for something more ambitious, look at `net/http` and the `httparty` gem.